# bbfreeze to compute python executable in python

Tags: python, executable

I have a python script which uses several other modules. Let's say i have following script:

```
test.py
-----------------
from xx include y
from aa include b
```

I used following script to compute executables of test.py

```
from bbfreeze import Freezer
f = Freezer("test_exe")
f.addScript("test.py")
f()
```

I got bbfreeze-console.exe om the folder named test_exe. Could you please let me know
what is wrong with it?